# user input value to use as decimal value python

Tags: python, expression, decimal, user-input

I am writing a python code where I ask the user for input and then I have to use their input to give the number of decimal places for the answer to an expression.

```
userDecimals = raw_input (" Enter the number of decimal places you would like in the final answer: ")
```

then I convert this to integer value

```
userDecimals = int(userDecimals)
```

then I write the expression, and I want the answer to have as many decimal places as the user input from UserDecimals, and I don't know how to accomplish this.

The expression is

```
math.sqrt(1 - xx **2)
```

If this isn't clear enough I will try to explain it better, but I am new to python, and I don't know how to do a lot yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and pass `userDecimals` to the `precision` part of the [format specifier](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> import math
>>> userDecimals = 6
>>> '{:.{}f}'.format(math.sqrt(1 - .1 **2), userDecimals)
'0.994987'
>>> userDecimals = 10
>>> '{:.{}f}'.format(math.sqrt(1 - .1 **2), userDecimals)
'0.9949874371'
```

Answer (score 0):

When formatting your print statement you can specify the number of significant figures to display.  For example `'%.2f' % float_value` will display two decimal places.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/python-limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points) for a more detailed discussion.

You want something like this:

```
import math

xx = .2

userDecimals = raw_input (" Enter the number of decimal places you would lik    e in the final answer: ")
userDecimals = int(userDecimals)

fmt_str = "%."+str(userDecimals)+"f"

print fmt_str % math.sqrt(1 - xx **2)
```

Outputs:

```
Enter the number of decimal places you would like in the final answer: 5
0.97980
```